# Julia: Canonical correlation analysis (canonical variates analysis) - how to get canonical vectors?

Tags: statistics, julia, correlation, svd, eigenvector

I am using the `fit(CCA,...)` function from the `MultivariateStats.jl` package and I want to know how to pull out the principal canonical vectors. The resulting `CCA` model object has methods like `xprojection` and `yprojection` which respectively give you the projection matrices that map the two random variables (the inputs `X` and `Y`) into their common, correlation-maximizing subspace. But I don't know how to simply extract the canonical vectors for each variable themselves, because I'm not familiar enough with the maths behind CCA/CVA to know how to compute them using the projection matrices and/or the 'mean vectors' (which is another provided method of the `CCA` object).

Anyone have familiarity with this?